# Apache FOP - render hyperlinks to PDF

Tags: xml, apache, xslt, pdf, apache-fop

I got a xml file with several blocks of text and lists. This will be rendered to a pdf using Apache FOP via a xsl transformation. The xsl is working however inside the xml are links defined like this `[abc|www.abc.com]` which should result in a link with abc as shown and www.abc.com as target.

The xsl equivalent would be this:
`<fo:basic-link external-destination="www.abc.com" show-destination="new">abc</fo:basic-link>`

However this links are inside text blocks and I do not know when they occure and when not. So what I need is a way to catch that and stuff and bring it into a form like the above where i do not know how would you do this in XSL?

A second way would be to implement some custom behaviour to the renderer but that could need a lot effort and i don't know where to hack in here.

Example input:

```
<fields>
  <field1>
   This is an example blog which contains the link [abc|www.abc.com] on a
   random position and it can contain a second link [abc2|www.abc2.com] like this
  </field1>
<fields>
```

Desired output:

**Field1:**
This is an example blog which contains the link [abc](http://abc.de) on a
random position and it can contain a second link [abc2](http://abc2.de) like this

Comment: I think you need to explicit your input and desired output a bit more. Could you give some explicite sample (I mean the input file and desired output file) ?

Comment: I added a example xml and the desired output which should be inside the pdf. What I have is that the field is inside the pdf only this special link syntax is missing and i currently have no good idea on how to solve this.

Comment: With what language are you transforming the xml to xsl fo? Are you using xslt?